# TFS 2012 update failed: Sync error for identity ... No mapping between account names and security IDs was done

Tags: tfs

Upgrading our TFS 2010 to TFS 2012, I get this error on one of the collections:

`[Error] Sync error for identity: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity, S-1-5-21-xxxxxxx - No mapping between account names and security IDs was done`

The upgrade fails. Re-running the servicing job from the admin console causes the same error.

I looked in the database, and there is an entry in `ADObjects` where both `SamAccountName` and `ObjectSID` have that SID. It looks like an account from an old domain. `fDeleted` is 1.

How do I clean this up so I can upgrade?

Added information (from the SQL trace):

`declare @p3 dbo.typ_ServicingStepDetail2
insert into @p3 values(1,'ToDev11Beta1FinalConfiguration','BuildToDev11Beta1FinalConfiguration','Grant Administer Build Permissions to Project Administrators','2013-04-12 14:17:55.617',NULL,0,N'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.IdentitySyncException: Sync error for identity: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity, S-1-5-21-xxxxx - No mapping between account names and security IDs was done
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationIdentityService.TryReadIdentityFromSourceInternal(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, IdentityDescriptor descriptor, Boolean withDirectMembership, TeamFoundationIdentity& identity)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationIdentityService.AddMemberToApplicationGroup(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, IdentityDescriptor groupDescriptor, IdentityDescriptor memberDescriptor, Boolean errorOnDuplicate, Boolean logSync, Boolean ensureKnown)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationIdentityService.EnsureIsMember(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, IdentityDescriptor groupDescriptor, IdentityDescriptor descriptor)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSecurityNamespace.EnsureIdentityIsKnownInternal(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, IdentityDescriptor identity, Boolean throwOnFailure)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSecurityNamespace.SetAccessControlEntries(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, String token, IEnumerable`1 accessControlEntries, Boolean merge, Boolean throwOnInvalidIdentity)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSecurityNamespace.SetAccessControlEntries(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, String token, IEnumerable`1 accessControlEntries, Boolean merge)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Servicing.TFCollection.BuildStepPerformer.GrantAdministerPermissionsToProjectAdmins(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, ServicingContext servicingContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationStepPerformerBase.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.IStepPerformer.PerformStep(String servicingOperation, String stepType, String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformServicingStep(ServicingStep step, ServicingContext servicingContext, ServicingStepGroup group, ServicingOperation servicingOperation, Int32 stepNumber, Int32 totalSteps)')
insert into @p3 values(2,'ToDev11Beta1FinalConfiguration','BuildToDev11Beta1FinalConfiguration','Grant Administer Build Permissions to Project Administrators','2013-04-12 14:17:55.617',5,NULL,NULL)

exec prc_AddServicingStepDetails @jobId='xxx',@queueTime='2013-04-12 14:17:50.840',@stepDetails=@p3,@hostId='xxx',@completedStepCount=419`

So it looks like I might have a project administrator who doesn't exist anymore. Any thoughts on how to remove that membership manually?

Comment: Is this just a version upgrade or did you change domains as well?

Comment: Version upgrade only. The domain upgrade happened long ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got the upgrade to complete by doing the following.

**THIS IS EXTREMELY FILTHY AND DANGEROUS. DO NOT TRY WITHOUT A GOOD BACKUP. YOUR WARRANTY HAS ALREADY EXPIRED. THIS VERY WELL MIGHT NOT WORK FOR YOU. IT MIGHT BREAK YOUR ENTIRE TFS SETUP AND GIVE DISEASES TO YOUR PUPPY.**

Anyway.

Open SQL Server Management Studio. Punch up a new query window for the project collection that won't upgrade (usually `Tfs_NameOfCollectionThatWontUpgrade`). Execute this command:

```
Select TeamFoundationId From ADObjects
Where ObjectSID='S-1-xxxx'
```

(Obviously, insert the proper SID from your error message.)

This will give you the internal GUID for the identity that is causing the problem. The step my upgrade failed on was giving Build Administrator rights to Project Administrators, and whoop-dee-doo, I can do that myself.

Now nuke the Active Directory link from orbit (you do have that GUID copied, right?)

```
Delete From ADObjects
Where ObjectSID='S-1-xxxxx'
```

(Obviously, insert the proper SID from your error message. Also note that this step might not be strictly necessary, but it is one I performed and I'll be damned if I roll back to see if you can do without it.)

Ah, gotta love chain-saw surgery. More to do. Let's remove this identity from all groups. **NOTE: if you do this to your only administrator account, you're likely to shut yourself out of the collection and/or the projects within. You have been warned.**

Switch to the configuration database (usually `Tfs_Configuration`) and execute

```
Delete From tbl_GroupMembership 
Where MemberId='The GUID you remembered'
```

At this point, the user is no longer a member of anything and the upgrade should complete. Everything should be there: builds, work items and source.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue (almost identical) when my TFS Server was using TFS 2012 Update 1.  I also came up with this hack in order to resolve it.  When I had a TFS Server running TFS 2012 RTM or TFS 2012 Update 2 I didn't encounter the issue.

Here a link to that thread.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsadmin/thread/238cad96-8e74-4f14-869a-3bb5e0629fd7